# How to test presence of a set of types in a collection of object of base type?

Tags: scala

I need to intersect types of incoming objects with a set of predefined ones.

The raw approach is to scan an incoming collection for each predefined type:

```
trait Field
class Field1 extends Field
class Field2 extends Field
class Field3 extends Field
...

class FieldManager(shownFields:Iterable[Field]) {
  var hiddenFields = new ArrayBuffer[Field]
  var found = false
  for (sf <- shownFields) {
    if (sf.isInstanceOf[Field1]) {
      found = true
      break
    }
  if (!found)
    hiddenFields+=new Field1
  for (sf <- shownFields) {
    if (sf.isInstanceOf[Field2]) {
      found = true
      break
    }
  if (!found)
    hiddenFields+=new Field2
  for (sf <- shownFields) {
    if (sf.isInstanceOf[Field3]) {
      found = true
      break
    }
  if (!found)
    hiddenFields+=new Field3
  ...
}
```

Wow, this is so verbose for Scala! There should be a shorter way. Like function template in C++:

```
class FieldManager {
  vector<Field*> hiddenFields, shownFields;
  template<class T>
  void fillHiddenType() {
    FOR_EACH(Field *, field, shownFields) {
      if (dynamic_cast<T*>(field))
        return
      hiddenFields.push_back(new T)
    }
  }
  void fillHidden() {
    fillHiddenType<Field1>();
    fillHiddenType<Field2>();
    fillHiddenType<Field3>();
    ...
  }
};
```

In this C++ example we mention each type to be scanned for only once.

Ok, Scala is also good for its type parameters, lets try:

```
def fillHiddenType[T] {
  for (sf <- shownFields)
    if (sf.isInstanceOf[T])
      return
  hiddenFields+=new T  
}
```

But compiler don't like creating T instance: `class type required but T found`. Try passing instance as argument and the next problem appears `warning: abstract type T in type is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` and `isInstanceOf[]` is always true! Type T is abstarcted so good, that is erased out completly even [T <: Field] doesn't allow to compare it to types from our collection shownFields.

The question is:
How to test presence of an object of a given type in a collection in a compact fashion?

**Update**
The following working code was tested on Scala 2.7.7 Both answers were useful. Thank you, guys!

```
//Scala 2.7.7 misses toSet members
implicit def toSet[T](i:Iterable[T]): Set[T] = {
    val rv = new HashSet[T]
    rv ++= i
    rv
}

def filterOut[T](all:Iterable[T], toRemove:Set[T]) = {
    all.filter(x => ! toRemove.contains(x))
}

def filterOutByType[T <: AnyRef](all:Iterable[T], toFilter:Set[T]):Iterable[T] = {
    def toClass(x:AnyRef) = x.getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
    val allTypes = all map toClass
    val extraTypes = toSet(filterOut(allTypes, toFilter map toClass))
    all.filter(extraTypes contains toClass(_))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maintain a set of known subclasses of `Field`, like so:

```
val allFieldClasses = Set[Class[_ <: Field]](
  classOf[Field1], 
  classOf[Field2],
  classOf[Field3],
  ...)
```

Then creating the hidden fields is simply a matter of filtering out the shown field classes from this set and constructing instances of the remaining ones:

```
def createHiddenFields(shownFields: Iterable[Field]):Set[Field] = {
  val toClass = (_:Field).getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Field]]
  (allFieldTypes -- (shownFields map toClass)) map (_.newInstance)
}
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to remember to keep `allFieldClasses` up-to-date when you add new subclasses of `Field`--the compiler won't warn you that your set isn't complete--but I see no way around that.

Comment: I accept this since it mention type lists first and seems to be actually tested with compiler ()

Comment: Yes, that bit of ugliness is because getClass() is a Java method defined on all objects, and therefore can't know the type parameter of the returned Class type.

Answer (score 6):

It's trivial to find the first member of a collection that has a given type:

```
shownFields.find(_.isInstanceOf[Field1])
```

but that'll still return an instance of `Option[Field]`, and not `Option[Field1]` - which you want for strong typing.  the collect method will help here:

```
showFields.collect{case x : Field1 => x}
```

Which will return an `Iterable[Field1]`, you can then use `headOption` to select the first element of the iterable as an `Option[Field1]`, either `Some[Field1]` if present, or `None` otherwise:

```
showFields.collect{case x : Field1 => x}.headOption
```

To make it more efficient, and not calculate ALL the Field1's in the list, I'd also make it lazy, via the `view` method:

```
showFields.view.collect{case x : Field1 => x}.headOption
```

and to then provide a default value if it's not found, use the `getOrElse` method that Options provide:

```
showFields.view.collect{case x : Field1 => x}.headOption getOrElse (new Field1)
```

**Update**

I just read back over the question, if seems you want hiddenFields to contain a new instance of every Field subtype for which there isn't a member in showFields.

To find all types represented in an `Iterable`:

```
val shownFieldTypes = showFields.map(_.getClass).toSet
```

(converting it to a set forces unique values)

If you then have a set of Fields you're interested in:

```
val allFieldTypes = Set(classOf[Field1], classOf[Field2], ...)
```

You can subtract to find the missing ones:

```
val hiddenFieldTypes = allFieldTypes -- shownFieldTypes
```

The catch here is that you'd then be stuck using newInstance, and reflection isn't always desirable... So:

```
val protoHiddenFields = Set(new Field1, new Field2, ...)
val allFieldTypes = protoHiddenFields.map(_.getClass)
val hiddenFieldTypes = allFieldTypes -- shownFieldTypes
val hiddenFields = protohiddenFields.filter(hiddenFieldTypes contains _.getClass)
```

The beauty of this approach is that your prototypes can be initialised using constructor parameters, if you so desire

Comment: Rather long for just first type of sequence. BTW, my classes are not case classes (case classes with argumentless constructors are deprecated).

Comment: But I'm not referring to case classes anywhere...  Case classes have an unapply method in the companion object which makes them easier to use with pattern matching, but they're certainly not the only thing that can be used in a pattern match!